# C++ reading strings,int,floats from a text file into a array/string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file-io

My .txt file contains the following

```
12345
John Smith
45 12.50
54234
Joe Paul
32 10.25
12324
Chris Lee
43 22.50
```

The first int is the employee ID, then the string name, then hours and rate of pay(float).

My Program:

```
using namespace std;

const int Size = 10;

typedef int intarray[Size];
typedef float farray[Size];
typedef string starray[Size];

void  readdata(intarray,starray,intarray,farray, ifstream &);
void  print(intarray,starray,intarray,farray,ifstream &);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("data.txt");
    //ofstream fout;

    starray EmployeeName;
    intarray EmployeeID,EmployeeHoursWorked;
farray EmployeeRate;

readdata(EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeHoursWorked,EmployeeRate,fin);
print(EmployeeID,EmployeeName,EmployeeHoursWorked,EmployeeRate,fin);
cin.get();
cin.ignore();
}
```

My functions, my code is not properly reading the file.

```
void readdata(intarray ID, starray Name, intarray Hours, farray Rate,    ifstream & infile)
{
for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
  {
//this code is not working as intended
   infile >> ID[i];
   getline(infile, Name[i]);
   infile >> Hours[i] >> Rate[i];

   infile.ignore();
 }     
}
```

Im not getting any results.

```
void print(intarray ID, starray Name, intarray Hours, farray Rate, ifstream & infile)
{
for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
  {
   cout << ID[i] << endl;
   cout<<Name[i]<<endl;
   cout << Hours[i] << Rate[i] << endl;


  }     
}
```

Comment: Re: P.S.: You could stuff your data into the arrays w/ assignment statements to get around the reading problem.

Comment: A little bit of error handling would go a long way.  Try adding a some code like `if (infile.bad()) cout << "can't read file";`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `print` should not be reading from any file.

Comment: Yeah, why do you have `infile` anywhere near your `print` function?

Comment: Oh, yeah. minor mistake. It still gives me wrong the output. it correctly reads the first line "12345" then spews out garbage/random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call getline in readdata you are reading the end of line character after the ID. You need to be positioned on the line with the name prior to calling getline. Try this

```
infile >> ID[i];
infile.ignore(); //Consume the new line char
getline(infile, Name[i]);
infile >> Hours[i] >> Rate[i];
```